# How can I reroute to and refresh the previous page after editing a table entry?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I have my edit view set to open in a new tab, save, close, and refresh the parent page. It works fine, but I want to keep the process in a single tab.

Here is what I am trying to do:
Click "Edit" from the table view, go to the edit view, make changes, save, then  reroute to the table view and refresh the page to display the changes.

The main issue is that it's a reporting site and an edit view for a single table entry can be accessed from multiple different report views(ex: "server list", "new servers"), so I can't do: `return view(SpecificURL)` upon saving.

I was wondering if I can implement some logic into the controller something similar to this:

```
if (PreviousPage == ViewA) { return view(ViewA) }

if (PreviousPage == ViewB) { return view(ViewB) }
```

or just have a simple: `return view(PreviousView)`

I am not sure how I would go about this.

Comment: I guess you could include that info as a parameter you pass to the Edit view. Then each page can pass a unique value to represent itself. Or you could make your Edit view a Partial view and have it pop up in a modal on each of these pages, you could load it (and its model data via AJAX instead. Then the user never leaves the original page at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single list page it will be straight forward. Can simply use -

return RedirectToAction("Index");

When you say edit view can be accessed from multiple different report views, you will have to pass the corresponding controller and action names to the edit view through query string values. Ex: returnController & returnAction (You could ignore returnAction if it is "Index" in all cases). After successful save in the edit action use the RedirectToAction overload with controller name.

RedirectToAction(returnAction, returnController);